# didSelectItemAtIndexPath does not get called when a custom collectionViewCell has label in it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom collectionViewCell with label covering the entire collectionViewCell size. Everything seems to work as planned but the only thing that doesn't seem to work is the collectionViewCell does not invoke `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. What is it that I am doing wrong? Why isn't UILabel passing the event to the superview. User Interaction is enabled on UILabel.

**EDIT: ADDING TAP GESTURE TO LABEL**

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ProductSizeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductSizeCollectionViewCell
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductDetailPageController.sizeTapped(_:)))
    cell.sizeLabel.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.sizeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return cell
 }


func sizeTapped(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let view  = sender.view as? UILabel
    print(view!.tag)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: view!.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = collectionViewSize.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductSizeCollectionViewCell
    if !cell.selectedCell {
        cell.selectedCell = true
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "9E9E9E").CGColor
    } else {
        cell.selectedCell = false
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "E8E6E4").CGColor
    }
    collectionViewSize.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: then add the gesture of your label and get gesture  action

Comment: Yeah I have done that but however on selecting one cell, selector seems to get fired multiple times.

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik check it out

Comment: Please put your code...

Comment: @Keyur check it out

Comment: did you set `delegate` for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` for your collectionview?

Comment: Yes I did. I delegated the collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have problem somewhere else. Can you double check if collection view delegate is truly set by log it on console?

Also:

```
collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ProductSizeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

should be set in some setup method once.

Because collection view (as table view) use reusable cells this line:

```
cell.sizeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

can add multiple gesture recognisers to one label. In that cases I prefer callback blocks fired by cell.